# Handling multiple objects in pytransitions

Tags: python, transition, state-machine, fsm, pytransitions

https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions

I was trying with the `batman = NarcolepticSuperhero("Batman")` example in the documentation.
But let's say if we have 100 batmans to handle, My approach is to create a list of every batman object and track their states individually using a loop.
IMO this is very naive.

Can some-one please suggest some effective solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all `NarcolepticSuperheros` should behave the same, I recommend to use one `Machine` for all 'batmen' instead of instantiating `NarcolepticSuperhero` a hundred times. This way, you can use `Machine.dispatch` to trigger an event on ALL models instead of looping through a list of superheroes (under the hood `Machine` also just loops through the model list though). I condensed the mentioned example a bit (all transitions in one list), removed the machine that was bound to `NarcolepticSuperheros` and introduced a `SuperheroDen`. Concerning state checking, you could use a dictionary to keep track of how many heroes are currently in what state. I added a `hero_log` to `NarcolepticSuperhero` and every time a hero changes its state, it will first log out of its current state and then log in with its new state.

```py
from transitions import Machine
from collections import  defaultdict
import random


class NarcolepticSuperhero(object):

    hero_log = defaultdict(list)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.kittens_rescued = 0

    def update_journal(self):
        self.kittens_rescued += 1

    @property
    def is_exhausted(self):
        return random.random() < 0.5

    @staticmethod
    def change_into_super_secret_costume():
        print("Beauty, eh?")

    def log_out(self):
        self.hero_log[self.state].remove(self)

    def log_in(self):
        self.hero_log[self.state].append(self)


class SuperheroDen(Machine):
    states = ['asleep', 'hanging out', 'hungry', 'sweaty', 'saving the world']
    transitions = [
        ['wake_up', 'asleep', 'hanging out'],
        ['work_out', 'hanging out', 'hungry'],
        ['eat', 'hungry', 'hanging out'],
        ['nap', '*', 'asleep'],
        dict(trigger='distress_call', source='*', dest='saving the world', before='change_into_super_secret_costume'),
        dict(trigger='complete_mission', source='saving the world', dest='sweaty', after='update_journal'),
        dict(trigger='clean_up', source='sweaty', dest='asleep', conditions=['is_exhausted']),
        ['clean_up', 'sweaty', 'hanging out'],
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(model=[NarcolepticSuperhero('Clone warrior') for i in range(100)],
                         states=self.states,
                         transitions=self.transitions,
                         # tell each model to 'log_out' right before state change
                         before_state_change='log_out',
                         # and to 'log_in' right after
                         after_state_change='log_in',
                         initial='asleep')
        # since our super heroes are asleep (and 'spawn' in their state), we have to log them in the first time
        for model in self.models:
            NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log[self.initial].append(model)


machine = SuperheroDen()
# trigger event 'wake_up' on all models
machine.dispatch('wake_up')
assert len(NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log['asleep']) == 0
assert len(NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log['hanging out']) == 100
for i in range(10):
    machine.models[i].work_out()
assert len(NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log['hanging out']) == 90
assert len(NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log['hungry']) == 10
assert machine.models[0] in NarcolepticSuperhero.hero_log['hungry']
```

Comment: hi @aleneum, Thanks for the idea, my bad actually this was mentioned in the doc. i see

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest sounds reasonable to me.

```
heros = [NarcolepticSuperhero(f"Batman{i:02d}")
         for i in range(100)]
```

Then either loop over all of them,
or use a `while True:` loop that sleeps a moment
then picks a hero at random.
Either way, you will have a hero
that you can trigger some new transition on.

Comment: Hi J_H, Thanks for answering, but the answer by aleneum, nearly suits my requirement :)